# Django - Is the path to my socket correct for nginx configuration

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

This is in my `site1_nginx.conf` which is present in the folder

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Now in my site1_nginx.conf , I specified the following

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/home/ec2-user/FooVenv/FooWeb/site1.socket; # for a file socket
   }
```

The path to my socket file is

```
/home/ec2-user/FooVenv/FooWeb/site1.socket;
```

However I am not sure if I specified it correct most of the samples I have seen have three leading `///`. Currently I am getting the error

> 2018/11/26 08:40:24 [emerg] 1253#0: invalid host in upstream
>   "/home/ec2-user/FooVenv/FooWeb/site1.socket" in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site1_nginx.conf:6 2018/11/26 08:41:37 [crit]
>   1276#0: *1 connect() to
>   unix:/home/ec2-user/FooVenv/FooWeb/site1.socket failed (13: Permission
>   denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.231.182.18, server:
>   qiggz.com, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://unix:/home/ec2-user/FooVenv/FooWeb/site1.socket:", host:
>   "www.foo.com:8000".

I have changed the actual web address to foo for security. Anyways I launched my uwsgi using this

```
 uwsgi --socket site1.socket --module main.wsgi --chmod-socket=777
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permission problem.

`chmod 664 /home/ec2-user/FooVenv/FooWeb/site1.socket`

Or make sure `uwsgi.ini` sets it properly and restart uwsgi:

`chmod-socket = 664`

Comment: Missed that. Not sure if typo or not but it should look like this: `--chmod-socket=777`. Alternatively you can try with `666` and restart nginx.

Comment: sorry it was a typo

Comment: `unix:///home/ec2-user/FooVenv/FooWeb/site1.socket` I think this is the correct syntax for nginx when specifying a socket.

Comment: Tried this seems like that does not work unfortunately